# Android Testing - App works on one phone, but crashes on others

Tags: android, testing

I created an app and it worked just fine on my phone, so I put it up on the market.  My friend tried downloading it first, and it does not work on her phone.  After the Splash Screen, it force closes.

I don't understand why this is happening.  I was under the impression that the market only allowed users with the correct devices to download the app, so figured this wouldn't be an issue.

Has anyone had this happen?  Also is there any way for me to test my app on all different phones to ensure that it will not crash again before re-posting it on the market?

**UPDATE - i had her run aLogCat and here is the result.  It was too many characters, so I copied from the first E/

```
E/CameraService(  166): Invalid Burst Count setting burst count to 1
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_set_parameters
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:311 setParameters - White balance set auto
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:321 setParameters - Antibanding set auto
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:337 setParameters - Exposure compensation set 0
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:343 setParameters - Scene mode set auto
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:363 setParameters - Flash mode set on
D/CameraHalM(  166): Current battery Level, 3425000 uv
D/CameraHalM(  166): flashIntensity = 50
E/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:374 setParameters - Setting KEY_MOT_LEDFLASH--50
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:384 setParameters - Effect set none
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:402 setParameters - Jpeg quality set 90
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:409 setParameters - Thumbnail width set 160
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:416 setParameters - Thumbnail width set 120
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:423 setParameters - Thumbnail quality set 60
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:470 setParameters - Zoom set 0
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:483 setParameters - Auto Exposure Lock set false
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:492 setParameters - Auto WhiteBalance Lock set false
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:507 setParameters - Focus mode set auto
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHalM.cpp:124 setMotParameters - Checking Image Stabilization param, off
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHalM.cpp:144 setMotParameters - Disabling Image Stabilization capturing
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHalM.cpp:189 setMotParameters - Led Torch : 0
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHalM.cpp:289 setMotTcmdParametersIfNeeded - Checking Mot Test Mode param, off
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHalM.cpp:300 setMotTcmdParametersIfNeeded - Disabling Test Mode
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:566 setParameters - PreviewFormat set yuv420sp
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:578 setParameters - VNF true
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:596 setParameters - VSTAB false
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:617 setParameters - IPP mode set ldc-nsf
D/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:652 setParameters - Sensor Orientation is set to 0
E/CameraHal(  166): (12785a0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:662 setParameters - Invalid preview resolution 960 x 540
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onInitialize : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onSetOnInfoListener : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onOpenDecryptSession by fd : 11
D/        (  165): filename = /system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onTerminate : 6579
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onInitialize : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onSetOnInfoListener : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onOpenDecryptSession by fd : 11
D/        (  165): filename = /system/media/audio/ui/multishot_click.ogg
D/AndroidRuntime( 4594): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 4594): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ac7210)
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onTerminate : 6579
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onInitialize : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onSetOnInfoListener : 6579
D/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onOpenDecryptSession by fd : 11
D/        (  165): filename = /system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg
I/OMXCodec(  166): isAudio=1, mMIME=audio/vorbis
V/MotDrmPlugIn(  165): MotDrmPlugIn::onTerminate : 6579
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1414)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity.surfaceChanged(ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity.java:425)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1662)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2558)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4594): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  375):   Force finishing activity sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity
I/OMXCodec(  166): isAudio=1, mMIME=audio/vorbis
I/OMXCodec(  166): isAudio=1, mMIME=audio/vorbis
I/AudioPlayer(  166): read from audio source returned: -1011
I/AudioPlayer(  166): read from audio source returned: -1011
I/AudioPlayer(  166): read from audio source returned: -1011
W/ApplicationContext(  375): Unable to create files directory files
D/ExtDispService(  667): onRotationChanged - rotation = 0
D/ExtDispService(  667): onRotationChanged! - PORTRAIT!!!
D/IExtDispIpcCB(  163): BnExtDispIpcCB NOTIFYCB: type:101; ext1:1; ext2:0;
D/HWC_HDMI_MOT(  163): IpcCB notifyCallback: type:101; ext1:1; ext2:0;
D/HWC_HDMI_MOT(  163): IpcCB notifyCallback: UI Orientation state change - rotation = 0
D/ti_hwc  (  163): hdmi_callback: UI Rotation = 0
I/InputReader(  375): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
I/InputReader(  375): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='atmxt-i2c', surface size is now 540x960, mode is 1
I/ActivityManager(  375): Config changed: {1.0 311mcc480mnc en_US layoutdir=0 sw360dp w360dp h614dp nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.6}
D/Swype   (  703): checkEditorShowsCompletions(): shows: false
I/PortalService(  817): onConfigurationChanged
D/OpenGLRenderer(  498): Flushing caches (mode 0)
V/RecentsPanelView(  498): onVisibilityChanged(com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView@41c57358, 8)
I/SystemUIService(  498): onConfigurationChanged reached.
I/SystemUIService(  498): isLayoutXLarge = false
D/EvbridgeService(  817): handleIntent() android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED handled by com.android.portal.EvbridgeService@413f4738
D/RecentsPanelView(  498): panelHeight=0
D/StatusBar.NetworkController(  498): Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED Received
D/ConnectivityService(  375): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
D/ConnectivityService(  375): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
D/OpenGLRenderer(  874): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/OpenGLRenderer(  874): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/Launcher.Model(  874): onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 }
W/ActivityManager(  375): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{414bfdd8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity}
D/Launcher.Model(  874): onReceive intent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 }
W/InputManagerService(  375): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41af34d0
W/Launcher(  874): localizable app group not found: Verizon Wireless
W/Launcher(  874): localizable app group not found: Verizon Wireless
W/Launcher(  874): localizable app group not found: Verizon Wireless
W/Launcher(  874): localizable app group not found: Verizon Wireless
I/ActivityManager(  375): No longer want com.google.android.talk (pid 4266): hidden #21
I/AlarmManager(  375): sending alarm Alarm{41ae30a0 type 2 com.android.phone}, PendingIntent{41b402e8: PendingIntentRecord{41d51cb8 com.android.phone broadcastIntent}}
V/AlarmManager(  375): sending alarm OnFinished PendingIntent{41b402e8: PendingIntentRecord{41d51cb8 com.android.phone broadcastIntent}}
D/AudioHardwareMot(  166): AudioStreamOutMot::standby called for 0x129c140
D/AudioHardwareMot(  166): Changed Min CPU Frequency to 300000 KHz
D/AudioHardwareMot(  166): Output 0x129c140 standby complete
D/dalvikvm(  375): GC_EXPLICIT freed 445K, 33% free 17236K/25635K, paused 9ms+7ms
I/Process ( 4594): Sending signal. PID: 4594 SIG: 9
W/InputManagerService(  375): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@420a4e80
W/InputDispatcher(  375): channel '420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(  375): channel '420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher(  375): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity (server)'
W/AudioFlinger(  166): session id 16 not found for pid 166
I/ActivityManager(  375): Process sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid (pid 4594) has died.
I/WindowManager(  375): WIN DEATH: Window{419c0168 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.SplashScreen paused=false}
I/WindowManager(  375): WIN DEATH: Window{420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity paused=false}
W/WindowManager(  375): Force-removing child win Window{417dc440 SurfaceView paused=false} from container Window{420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity paused=false}
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_disable_msg_type
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/CameraHal.cpp:225 disableMsgType - Disabling Preview Callback
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_stop_preview
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_cancel_picture
E/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1791 setState - Adapter state switch INTIALIZED_STATE Invalid Op! event = 0x5
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_release
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/SensorListener.cpp:223 disableSensor - orientation = 0x12e1518 (LIS3DH 3-axis Accelerometer)
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/SensorListener.cpp:108 ~SensorListener - Kill looper thread
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/SensorListener.cpp:120 ~SensorListener - Kill looper
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/SensorListener.cpp:126 ~SensorListener - SensorListener destroyed
I/CameraService(  166): Destroying camera 0
V/CameraHal(  166): camera_device_close
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1797 stop -  --> AppCallbackNotifier NOTIFIER_STOPPED 
D/CameraHal(  166): (12e35b8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:287 notificationThread - Notification Thread received message from Camera HAL
D/CameraHal(  166): (12e35b8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1236 processMessage - +Msg get...
D/CameraHal(  166): (12e35b8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1238 processMessage - -Msg get...
I/CameraHal(  166): Received NOTIFIER_EXIT command from Camera HAL
D/CameraHal(  166): (12e35b8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:290 notificationThread - Notification Thread exiting.
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1301 ~AppCallbackNotifier - Stopping Event Provider
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/AppCallbackNotifier.cpp:1309 ~AppCallbackNotifier - Stopping Frame Provider
D/CameraHal(  166): (12ca020)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:1389 switchToLoaded - Already in OMX_Loaded state or OMX_StateInvalid state
W/WindowManager(  375): Failed looking up window
W/WindowManager(  375): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@41af7900 does not exist
W/WindowManager(  375): at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7606)
W/WindowManager(  375): at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7597)
W/WindowManager(  375): at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1579)
W/WindowManager(  375): at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:433)
W/WindowManager(  375): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
I/WindowManager(  375): WIN DEATH: null
I/WindowManager(  375): WINDOW DIED Window{420f92e8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity paused=false}
D/CameraHal(  166): (12d76d0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:3571 Handler - msg.command = -1
D/CameraHal(  166): (12d76d0)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:3585 Handler - Exiting command handler
D/CameraHal(  166): (12d2c40)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXCameraAdapter.cpp:3628 Handler - Exiting OMX callback handler
I/AlarmManager(  375): sending alarm Alarm{41b2e7d8 type 3 android}, PendingIntent{42116fc0: PendingIntentRecord{421063c0 android broadcastIntent}}
V/AlarmManager(  375): sending alarm OnFinished PendingIntent{42116fc0: PendingIntentRecord{421063c0 android broadcastIntent}}
D/PortalService(  817): Portal onReceive: 
I/PortalService(  817): onHandleIntent() action android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
I/ActivityManager(  375): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.motorola.blur.home/.Launcher} from pid 375
I/ActivityManager(  375): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=org.jtb.alogcat cmp=org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity bnds=[8,65][137,245]} from pid 874
D/OpenGLRenderer(  874): Flushing caches (mode 1)
D/Swype   (  703): checkEditorShowsCompletions(): shows: false
I/ActivityManager(  375): Resumed Activity: org.jtb.alogcat/.LogActivity totalTime: 91 ms
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  874): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/OpenGLRenderer(  874): Flushing caches (mode 0)
D/dalvikvm( 4564): GC_CONCURRENT freed 666K, 5% free 11986K/12579K, paused 1ms+17ms
D/Swype   (  703): checkEditorShowsCompletions(): shows: false
W/ActivityManager(  375): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{414930d8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/.SplashScreen}
W/ActivityManager(  375): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{414bfdd8 sillyfidget.com.shakeitpolaroid/.ShakeItLikeAPolaroidActivity}
```

Comment: Ask your friend to download an app called 'aLogCat', then send you the log that contains the crash logs of your app. Then post it here so we can see why it crashed.

Comment: You should provide any details about crashing, logcat output, anything... Nobody will be able to say why your app crashes, without knowing at least what it does...

Comment: I'm sorry...I had no way of telling because it works fine for me on my phone.  I just asked her to DL the aLogCat app.  I will post what she sends me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your friend mobile android level is different with your mobile android level.

Some times the app does not work in all Android phones. If you want to check it you must follow these steps

```
 1) Change your app target in manifest as minsdkversion 8 and target sdk version 15.

 2) test your app in all emulators.

 3) test each module (working of each activity) in all emulators.
```

You will definitely find some errors if you do like this. Good luck

Comment: @SillyFidget For what? He told you that some apps don't work on all devices, which you obviously already knew. This does not answer your question, it really has nothing to do with your problem either. While his suggestion may be a good idea as a general rule your problem is very specific and pretty obvious to anyone who actually takes the time to review your log output before answering.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're passing invalid parameters in Camera.setParameters, not all cameras support the same features so you should be querying the camera for it's capabilities before calling that method. However if I were you I'd maybe start a bit smaller because it appears that you are a little over your head here.  At the very least you should know how to recognize relevant log info and debug basic problems like this.

FYI: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html